# Plotting power curve for a two-sided binomial test in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

```
n = 30
p = 0.35
p_hat_seq = seq(0, 1, 0.01)
sd = sqrt((p * (1 - p)/n))
z = (p_hat_seq - p)/sd
plot(pnorm(z), type = "l", ylab = "Power")
```

[image]

Here the sample size n = 30. p = 0.35, and `p_hat_seq` contains my sample proportions. I plotted a (what I believe to be) one tailed power function. However, if I want to test H0: p = 0.35 vs. H1: p != 0.35. How would I plot the power function?

Comment: Why are you plotting against index? what did you mean to have on the x-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 30
p = 0.35
sd = sqrt((p * (1 - p)/n))

c1<-qnorm(0.025,p,sd)
c2<-qnorm(0.975,p,sd)
p_hat_seq = seq(0, 1, 0.01)
power<-pnorm(c1,p_hat_seq,sd)+1-pnorm(c2,p_hat_seq,sd)
plot(p_hat_seq, power, type = "l", ylab = "Power" )
```

[image]